# How to implement interactive sorting in Report Viewer in VS 2010?

Tags: report-viewer2010

I have created a report with report viewer in visual studio 2010. Please help me out on how to implement interactive sorting(end users must be able to sort. Sort icons must be displayed on the column) for a column in the report?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you go to the report in the designer, rightclick the column you wish to add interactive sorting, then go to table/tablix properties, there should be an "Interactive Sorting" tab or "Sorting" tab with a check box to enable Interactive Sorting. (Sorry for uncertainty, going from memory atm)

(More Information Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627509.aspx and http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/ForumTopic.aspx?lang=en&topic_id=2444&forum_id=56)